# Under what conditions a diagonal matrix is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

I found in this answer :

[Identity Matrix = Orthogonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678315/identity-matrix-orthogonal)

That the  diagonal should have an absolute value $= 1$

But I don't see exactly why.. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The answer you have posted has an answer to your problem by Alex Ortiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $A^TA=I$. If $A$ is diagonal, then the $i$th diagonal entry of $A^TA$ is $a_{ii}^2$ and must equal $1$